# What are the other alternatives of Docker Desktop to run a container on Window machine

Tags: docker

I was using Docker desktop to run docker containers on my window 10 machine.
But now I have to uninstall the docker desktop due to the licensing.
What are the other alternatives to run containers in my window machines ?

Comment: You can run Docker in WSL without Docker desktop but you will loose some of the seamless integration with debugging from Visual Studio and other handy features.

Comment: Do you have the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2?) That's a real Linux. See https://dev.to/bowmanjd/install-docker-on-windows-wsl-without-docker-desktop-34m9

Comment: I was not really aware of the WSL2 feature. will try this solution. Thanks

Comment: I'm running a Hyper-V Linux VM and run Docker on that. There's no Windows integration, but there were too many quirks in WSL2 for my taste.